# Extract text in between two strings if a sub-string present in between those two strings

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a raw text in a column named "message" as shown below:

**Example dataframe**

```
Date               message
2020-11-01         ['some not required text1', 'Startstring , 
                   'some not required text2', MandatorySubstring , 'some not 
                    required text3', 'ID :AB_CD, 'Stopstring' 'some not 
                    required text4', 'Startstring ID :cd_ab', 'some not 
                    required text5', 'ID :ghed','some not required text6', ID :zyx', 'Stopstring 'some 
                    not required text7']
2020-11-02         ['some not required text8', Startstring 'ID :ABCD', 
                   'some not required text9', 'ID :ED_GH', 'some not 
                    required text10', ID :X_YZ, Stopstring 'some not 
                    required text11', 'Startstring 
                    'some not required text12',MandatorySubstring 
                    'some not required text13', ID :z_yx', 'some not required text14''Stopstring 
                    'some not required text15']
```

I am looking to extract the string just after ID : in between Startstring and Stopstring if MandatorySubstring exists between Startstring and Stopstring and discarding the IDs if MandatorySubstring doesn't exists between Startstring and Stopstring. There may be multiple such instances in one Date.

**Expected Output:**

```
Date               message
2020-11-01         AB_CD 
2020-11-02         z_yx
```

**I tried following pattern:**

```
pattern = StartString\s*((?:(?!StartString).)*?MandatoryString 1.*?)\s*Stopstring
```

It gives me all text between the startstring and stoptstring. I have no clue how to extract text just after ID: from this text now.

Can Anyone provide me Regex pattern for this scenario? Help in this regard is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I think your example is missing some closing quotes?

Comment: That should not matter. Datatype for column named "message" is str and the whole value in front of each date is just one string (raw text). Hope that clarified your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the current input, I'd suggest

```py
Startstring(?:(?!Startstring).)*?MandatorySubstring(?:(?!Startstring).)*?,['\s]*ID\s*:\s*([^',]*).*?Stopstring
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RSzf62/2). Details:

- `Startstring` - a left-hand delimiter
- `(?:(?!Startstring).)*?` - any zero or more chars each of which does not start a `Startstring` char sequence
- `MandatorySubstring` - a string that must be present in between left- and right-hand delimiters
- `(?:(?!Startstring).)*?` - any zero or more chars each of which does not start a `Startstring` char sequence
- `,` - a comma
- `['\s]*` - zero or more `'` or whitespace
- `ID`  - a string
- `\s*:\s*` - colon enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `([^',]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `'` and `,`
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `Stopstring` - right-hand delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in three stages. First, use regex to search these strings for the start string, mandatory substring, and stop string. We use negative lookahead assertions to ensure the mandatory substring does indeed lie between two adjacent start and stop strings. Once we have these matches, we extract the IDs present in each one, and finally condense these down into a single list.

```
def extract_ids(s):
    matches = re.findall(r'Startstring((?:(?!Startstring).)*)MandatorySubstring((?:(?!Stopstring).)*)Stopstring', s)
    all_ids = [re.findall(r'ID\s*:([^,]*)', group) for match in matches for group in match]
    ids_flat = [i for l in all_ids for i in l]
    return ids_flat

s1 = """['some not required text1', 'Startstring , 'some not required text2', MandatorySubstring , 'some not required text3', 'ID :AB_CD, 'Stopstring' 'some not required text4', 'Startstring ID :cd_ab', 'some not required text5', 'ID :ghed','some not required text6', ID :zyx', 'Stopstring 'some not required text7']"""

s2 = """['some not required text8', Startstring 'ID :ABCD', 'some not required text9', 'ID :ED_GH', 'some not required text10', ID :X_YZ, Stopstring 'some not required text11', 'Startstring 'some not required text12',MandatorySubstring 'some not required text13', ID :z_yx', 'some not required text14''Stopstring 'some not required text15']"""

>>> extract_ids(s1)
['AB_CD']

>>> extract_ids(s2)
["z_yx'"]
```

To apply this to your dataframe, just use `df['message'].map(extract_ids)`.

Comment: Edited my question for clarity. please have a look. Thanks